# Troubleshooting socket.io event system in Node backend/Angular frontend

Tags: node.js, angular, socket.io

I need to set up a simple event system in a Node backend to notify the clients (Angular application) when certain events happen (f.i. when a user changes his profile photo). I'm using socket.io library in the backend and its equivalent 'ngx-socket-io' in the frontend. This is what I've done so far:

**Backend - 'bin/www' (server initial script)**

```
// 'server' is created using 'http.createServer()'
const io = require('socket.io')(server);

// Set the socket.io object in the main app object to access it from anywhere
app.set('socketio', io);

io.on('connection', socket => {
    logger.debug('Socket connected: ', socket.id);

    socket.on('disconnect', () => {
        logger.debug('Socket disconnected: ', socket.id);
    });
});
```

**Backend - 'controllers/user.js' (User routes controller)**

```
controller.changeProfilePhoto = function(req, res) {        
    // Socket IO object
    const socketio = req.app.get('socketio');

    // Do the stuff to change the profile photo...

    if(socketio) {
        socketio.emit("appevent", { msg: 'Profile photo updated', user: req.body.userId });
    }
}
```

**Frontend - 'services/app-events.service.ts' (App events service)**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Socket } from 'ngx-socket-io';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AppEventsService {

  constructor(private socket: Socket) { }

  sendMessage(msg: string) {
    this.socket.emit("appevent", msg);
  }

  getMessage(): Observable<any> {
    return this.socket.fromEvent("appevent");
  }
}
```

I subscribe to `getMessage` in the components that I need to update when some events happen, but I don't receive any. In the backend, I can see a message each time a client connects:

> Socket connected:  Wv8-DXqMaPi_dhRIAAAA

What could be wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The problem had nothing to do with socket.io, but with the way to reach the backend from the clients. I'm using a reverse proxy to avoid opening an extra port for the API in the firewall, and I was using a wrong URL in the socket.io connection.

In case someone needs it, this is the `proxy.conf.json` file I'm using:

```
{
    "/api": {
        "target": "http://localhost:3000",
        "secure": false,
        "logLevel": "debug",
        "pathRewrite": {
            "^/api": ""
        }
    },
    "/socket.io": {
        "target": "http://localhost:3000",
        "secure": false,
        "logLevel": "debug",
        "ws": true
    }
}
```

The URL for the socket.io connection must be the client's base address, as we can see with the following example:

- Client address: http://localhost:4200
- Socket.io will add a new endpoint to it: http://localhost:4200/socket.io
- Following the rule in the proxy configuration, '/socket.io' will be translated to 'http://localhost:3000/socket.io'

Hope it helps, cheers!